# After disassembly, Switch screen is black even though backlight and touchscreen still work, and console outputs video while in the dock

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-switch, hardware

I recently started a project to replace the shell/case of my Switch with a transparent atomic purple version to get the classic '90s Nintendo look. I bought the case from eXtremeRate, and all the proper tools for disassembly from iFixit. Prior to this my Switch was in working condition with no issues.

I followed the [iFixit guide for Front Frame Replacement,](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nintendo+Switch+Front+Frame+Replacement/148737) and after I reassembled most of it (see pic) I turned the Switch on to test. This was when I discovered that the Switch's screen would not display anything. The backlight would turn on and "light up" the black screen, and when I touched the screen the Switch will make noises indicating that it's registering those touches. When I put the Switch into the dock, it would still output video to the TV and work normally.

I figured that somehow I damaged the screen or one of the ribbon cables, so I ordered a replacement screen from iFixit. I went through that repair, and returned the Switch to the same stage it had been in for the first test. The issue is still present even with the new screen though and nothing has changed. The screen is still black, backlight and touchscreen still work, and it still outputs video when in the dock.

I'm now unsure what the issue is with my Switch and how to proceed. What is the likely cause of this issue, and how do I repair it?

Current state of my Switch: microSD card reader and shield plate are removed, everything else is installed and connected. The microSD reader has been attached for some tests, and nothing changed. The only component that hasn't been reinstalled for a test is the shield plate.
[image: Current state of my Switch: microSD card reader and shield plate are removed, everything else is installed.]